# Problems deploying a release version of app with linking enabled

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

We want to go-live with a project where the release version is not working when linking is enabled. So we isolated the problem in a minimal project setting with 2 projects:

- PCL project: dvit.appfwk.core
- Android project: dvit.appfwk.droid

Android project: dvit.appfwk.droid

The PCL project has the following profile:

[image: appProfile]

In the PCL project we define an interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace dvit.appfwk.core
{
    public interface IAzureService
    {
        MobApp MobAppGetItem (int id);
    }
}
```

In the droid project we put the implementation:

```
public MobApp MobAppGetItem (int id)
{
    IMobileServiceTable<MobApp> mobAppTable = MobileService.GetTable<MobApp> ();

    var mobAppQry = mobAppTable.Where (x => x.Id == id);

    var mobApps = mobAppQry.ToListAsync ().Result;

    if (mobApps.Count > 0)
        return mobApps [0];
    else
        return null;
}
```

We use this method in the PCL in the class "FirstViewModel" (with all the IOC magic). This implementation works perfectly in Debug mode and in Release mode (without linking). But our app takes too much space & RAM, so we want to enable the linking, but then the app does not work anymore and the problem appears to be the line of code:
var mobApps = mobAppQry.ToListAsync ().Result;

The problem is somehow linked to the usage of the async functionality.
I added the output of the "adb logcat -s" command at the bottom of the post. 
 We have not found a decent post explaining how to tackle the linking problem in MvvMCross, I’m really hoping someone can push us in the right direction.

```
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   0.23 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   0.36 Problem creating viewModel of type FirstViewModel - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
E/appfwk  ( 2202):        at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization
o culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.TryLoad (System.Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterValues, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModel& viewMo
00] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202): InnerException was ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
E/appfwk  ( 2202): Parameter name: method
E/appfwk  ( 2202):        at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure, Boolean allowClo
00] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.CreateLambda (System.Type delegateType, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, System.Coll
ectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <fil
wn>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename

E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.PartialEvaulator+<EvaluateIndependentSubtrees>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__7 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Func`2 rec
0] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept (System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<Visit>__BaseCallProxy0 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.<Visit>m__8 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.PartialEvaulator+<EvaluateIndependentSubtrees>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__7 (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Func`2 rec
0] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.VisitorHelper.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
E/appfwk  ( 2202):   at System.Linq.Expre
E/appfwk  ( 2219):   0.00 Setup: PlatformServices start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the Preserve attribute to types/members you want the linker not to touch.

```
public class Example {
    [Android.Runtime.Preserve]
    public Example ()
    {
    }
}

[Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers=true)]
class Example {
    // Compiler provides default constructor...
}
```

The [Linker](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/) guide (there's one for both iOS and Android) are both pretty good.

EDIT: What Alexey said is correct.

Add an XML file similar to the one below to your project and set it's Build Action to **LinkDescription**.

```
<linker>
        <assembly fullname="My.Own.Assembly">
                <type fullname="Foo" preserve="fields" />
                        <method name=".ctor" />
                </type>
                <type fullname="Bar" />
                        <method signature="System.Void .ctor(System.String)" />
                        <field signature="System.String _blah" />
                </type>
        </assembly>
</linker>
```

Comment: How about if i want to preserve something in my .Core class wich is a portable class library containing no android assemblies what so ever? There i don't have access to the [Preserve] attribute.

Comment: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/ read under "Custom Linking".